# replaceChild changes spacing for a second while loading replacement image

Tags: javascript, css

thanks in advance for the help.  so on my site i have 2 images sitting next to each other in the same div.  I am using replaceChild to replace the first image.  Everything is working, but when it removes the first image, the second image shifts to the left for a split second before the new image is loaded and placed in the first images spot.

Do you guys have any ideas on how i can make the second image stay in its spot while the first image disappears and then gets replaced?

Edit: Found a way that i could preload the page [HERE](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript/) that ended up working great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's several options here:

1. Use the css property for position to keep both images in place within their parent (they aren't dependent on eachother)
2. Place each image in a div with hard-coded size
3. Hard-code the image's height/width and just replace the src attribute

Comment: I tried changing the property to absolute and static to see if that would work, but the problem is that the entire div seems to shrink (i have it set to be as wide as the elements in it) so everything including the border was moving left on the page.  So the picture seemed to still be moving.  (im new to this, so highly possible i was doing it wrong).  ended up finding a way to preload the image that seemed to work. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<img id="image1" src="image1.png" alt="image1" />
<img id="image2" src="image2.png" alt="image2" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div
{
   overflow:hidden;
   width:200px; 
}
#image1
{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   float:left;
}
#image2
{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   float:right;
}
```

By giving the **DIV** and the **img** a fixed width, and using **float**, I think the second image will stay in place,give it a try.

Comment: I tried this and it worked great with my 2 images.  the problem i came across was if i wanted to add a 3rd image to the page (i know i didn't mention this in the original question), it would end up in the middle since i had the float right.  worked great for the 2 though.  thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @David then if you don't know if you're gonna add more and more images, use a <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>, and add as much cells (images) as you like, and give all cells a fixed width and height, then you won't need to use float.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

1. Load the new image in a hidden spot.
2. Remove the old image
3. Then unhide the new image and move it into place.

This just reduces the time the old image is gone before the new one goes into place.

Comment: This actually gave me the idea to just load both of the images and load the old one on top and then remove that to show the one that is below.  So as i was looking into that, i actually came across a way to [preload](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/09/12/preloading-images-jquery-and-javascript/) the image. So i went that route and that seems to work.  Thanks lee!